# SAS Converting Characters/Number to Numbers

Tags: sas

I am looking for a way to convert the characters into numbers in SAS so that I can use the max function. Also, it would be helpful if the characters and only the numbers are kept. Below is a list of data for a column in a SAS table.

**Column UNK**
abc20140714
abc20140714x
abc20140714xyz
123_abc20140714_xyz
abc20150718

After stripping out the number values from the column, I would then group the data and use the max function in SAS, which should only generate the value 20150718.

To avoid any confusion, my question, is there a way to strip out the non-numeric values, and then convert the column into a numeric column so I can use the max function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure!

```
var_num = input(compress(var_char,,'kd'),yymmdd8.);
```

Compress removes or keeps characters from a list.  `'kd'` says to 'keep digits'.

You then input using the appropriate informat; `yymmdd8.` looks right based on the data you provide.  Then apply a format, `format var_num yymmdd8n.;` or similar, so it looks like a date visually (even if it's really a number underneath).

As pointed out, this won't work if there are *other* numeric digits in the values; you need to look at your data and identify how those appear and clean them out separately. You could use a regular expression for example to identify things that have 8 consecutive digits, starting with a 20; but ultimately it is a data analysis issue to handle these as your data require.

Comment: Good answer, the only problem is it doesn't appear to work on "123_abc20140714_xyz" because the 123 is kept as part of the number.

Comment: I should've addressed that and will, but I would consider that outside the scope of this question as it's a data problem that is different than the main question.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first sequence of 8 digits in a row starting with a 1 or a 2 as a numeric value, you can use the following:

```
data want;
    set have;
    pos = prxmatch("/[12]\d{7}/", character_string);
    if pos > 0 then number = input(substr(character_string, pos, 8), 8.);
    else number = .;
    drop pos;
run;
```

The prxmatch expression finds the starting position of the sequence, and the substr expression extracts the sequence, then the input function converts it to a numeric.

(Edited to incorporate Joe's feedback)